# PhoneGap Push Plugin Does Not Register iOS 8 Device

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

The plugin at version 2.3.1, iOS 8.0, iPhone 5. Everything worked find before iOS 8. I upgraded the plugin, before it was 2.0.5. Neither a success nor an error response is received when calling register:

```
window.plugins.pushNotification.register(

     // tokenHandler (iOS ony) - called when the device has registeredwith a unique device token.
     function (result) {

        alert('device token = ' + result);


     },

    function(error) {
       alert('error = ' + JSON.stringify(error));


    }, 

      {
        "badge":"true",
        "sound":"true",
        "alert":"true",
        "ecb":"onNotificationAPN"
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the pull requests on github.

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/pulls

There are lots of iOS8 Fixes included.  It doesn't look like they are merged into the phonegap-build repository yet.

iOS8 changed the way they register and handle push notifications so there are some code changes you will need to update to support iOS8.

Answer (score 1):

Change the PushPlugin.m

- (void)register:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
  {
  self.callbackId = command.callbackId;

  NSMutableDictionary* options = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

  UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone;
  id badgeArg = [options objectForKey:@"badge"];
  id soundArg = [options objectForKey:@"sound"];
  id alertArg = [options objectForKey:@"alert"];

  if ([badgeArg isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
  {
      if ([badgeArg isEqualToString:@"true"])
          notificationTypes |= UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge;
  }
  else if ([badgeArg boolValue])
      notificationTypes |= UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge;

  if ([soundArg isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
  {
      if ([soundArg isEqualToString:@"true"])
          notificationTypes |= UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
  }
  else if ([soundArg boolValue])
      notificationTypes |= UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;

  if ([alertArg isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
  {
      if ([alertArg isEqualToString:@"true"])
          notificationTypes |= UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert;
  }
  else if ([alertArg boolValue])
      notificationTypes |= UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert;

  self.callback = [options objectForKey:@"ecb"];
  if(self.callback!=nil&&[self.callback length]){
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
       setObject:self.callback forKey:@"CallBack"];
  }

  if (notificationTypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone)
      NSLog(@"PushPlugin.register: Push notification type is set to none");

  isInline = NO;

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:notificationTypes];

  if (notificationMessage)            // if there is a pending startup notification
      [self notificationReceived];    // go ahead and process it
  }

**

> Change like this

**

- (void)register:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
  {
  self.callbackId = command.callbackId;

  NSMutableDictionary* options = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

  UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone;
  id badgeArg = [options objectForKey:@"badge"];
  id soundArg = [options objectForKey:@"sound"];
  id alertArg = [options objectForKey:@"alert"];

  if ([badgeArg isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
  {
      if ([badgeArg isEqualToString:@"true"])
          notificationTypes |= UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge;
  }
  else if ([badgeArg boolValue])
      notificationTypes |= UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge;

  if ([soundArg isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
  {
      if ([soundArg isEqualToString:@"true"])
          notificationTypes |= UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
  }
  else if ([soundArg boolValue])
      notificationTypes |= UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;

  if ([alertArg isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
  {
      if ([alertArg isEqualToString:@"true"])
          notificationTypes |= UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert;
  }
  else if ([alertArg boolValue])
      notificationTypes |= UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert;

  self.callback = [options objectForKey:@"ecb"];
  if(self.callback!=nil&&[self.callback length]){
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
       setObject:self.callback forKey:@"CallBack"];
  }

  if (notificationTypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone)
      NSLog(@"PushPlugin.register: Push notification type is set to none");

  isInline = NO;

  //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:notificationTypes];
  **//For Iphone 8
  if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
  {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
  }
  else
  {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
       (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
  }**

  if (notificationMessage)            // if there is a pending startup notification
      [self notificationReceived];    // go ahead and process it
  }

Comment: Could you make this into a gist or a diff for a github repo? Easier to follow that way.